# Event "onchange" calling javascript inside Joomla! 3.x seems not to work

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange, joomla3.0

I'm removing the rust and getting to do some php/javascript programming again, after a while. I'm developing a website for an event, to which people have to register themselves in order to participate. 
Here's the situation: I made a form where participants can choose presentations to reserve their spot. Here's the js function I'm using:

```
function cbosoma(obj, valor) {
    var valoratual = document.getElementById("total").value;
    var newval = 0;
    // Alert windows - just for testing 
    alert("You just marked or unmaked a checkbox!");
    if (isNaN(valoratual) || valoratual < 0 ) {
        valoratual = 0;
    }
    if (obj.checked) { 
        newval = parseInt(valoratual) + parseInt(valor);
    } else {
        newval = valoratual - valor;
    }
    document.getElementById("total").value = newval;
}
```

So, when the user checks or unchecks courses they wanna participate, their "bill" ("total" input text label) should be increased or decrease. The test alert should also pop up on the screen, just to confirm that the script is being called. Here's how I called the function from inside the PHP code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="100" onchange='cbosoma(this, this.value)'>
```

The problem is: I tested this on a separated test page and it worked just fine. However, inside Joomla!, nothing happens. I tried everything: using js control modules, calling the script as a .js file, putting it inside my PHP file using `<script>` tags, putting the script inside Joomla!'s index.php... Nothing worked.

Can someone give me some advise on that, please?

Comment: Any especific error on console?

Comment: File path issue? Caching? Not much for us to go on here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I put the code into the source code directly. If I put some alert('hello world!") instead of the function, the alert shows - so it seems js runs OK. The problem seems to be with the onchange event itself. I don't know if mootools or some other js that comes with Joomla 3.5 may be affecting it...

Comment: Dear Marvin Medeiros: just realized the error below when reading the line: "newval = parseInt(valoratual) + parseInt(valor);" :

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

I just can't tell where is the error... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Fellows, I guess I found the problem - and it was kind of dummie... It turns out the <input> I was reading with document.getElementById("total").value was with name="total" instead of id="total". That was causing the problem. I just didn't remember I could use F12 to debug - I'm really rusty... Thanks a lot for your help, guys!!!